# SCSS to CSS error, Prepros not able to give CSS

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to convert an SCSS file into CSS. My intention is to convert the colors defined in SCSS file into hex codes in CSS file. I tried, `Prepros` and `Koala`. Both failed to gave a `colours.css` file from `colours.scss`. But it was 0 bytes file.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Now I tried command line after installing SASS through npm.

```
$ sass colours.scss colours.css
```

Now I have 2 new files

1. colours.css which says

> /*# sourceMappingURL=colours.css.map */

2. colours.css.map which says

> {"version":3,"sourceRoot":"","sources":[],"names":[],"mappings":"","file":"colours.css"}

These are the only contents of that file.

I took the colours.css file from

> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss

so that I can get the hex codes for colours included in this file.

I have included below the contents of colours.scss which I took from the github file. I need only the colours part. If possible, please help me fix this problem.

```css
// Color system

$white:    #fff !default;
$gray-100: #f8f9fa !default;
$gray-200: #e9ecef !default;
$gray-300: #dee2e6 !default;
$gray-400: #ced4da !default;
$gray-500: #adb5bd !default;
$gray-600: #6c757d !default;
$gray-700: #495057 !default;
$gray-800: #343a40 !default;
$gray-900: #212529 !default;
$black:    #000 !default;

$grays: () !default;
// stylelint-disable-next-line scss/dollar-variable-default
$grays: map-merge(
  (
    "100": $gray-100,
    "200": $gray-200,
    "300": $gray-300,
    "400": $gray-400,
    "500": $gray-500,
    "600": $gray-600,
    "700": $gray-700,
    "800": $gray-800,
    "900": $gray-900
  ),
  $grays
);

$blue:    #0d6efd !default;
$indigo:  #6610f2 !default;
$purple:  #6f42c1 !default;
$pink:    #d63384 !default;
$red:     #dc3545 !default;
$orange:  #fd7e14 !default;
$yellow:  #ffc107 !default;
$green:   #28a745 !default;
$teal:    #20c997 !default;
$cyan:    #17a2b8 !default;

$colors: () !default;
// stylelint-disable-next-line scss/dollar-variable-default
$colors: map-merge(
  (
    "blue":       $blue,
    "indigo":     $indigo,
    "purple":     $purple,
    "pink":       $pink,
    "red":        $red,
    "orange":     $orange,
    "yellow":     $yellow,
    "green":      $green,
    "teal":       $teal,
    "cyan":       $cyan,
    "white":      $white,
    "gray":       $gray-600,
    "gray-dark":  $gray-800
  ),
  $colors
);

$primary:       $blue !default;
$secondary:     $gray-600 !default;
$success:       $green !default;
$info:          $cyan !default;
$warning:       $yellow !default;
$danger:        $red !default;
$light:         $gray-100 !default;
$dark:          $gray-800 !default;

$theme-colors: () !default;
// stylelint-disable-next-line scss/dollar-variable-default
$theme-colors: map-merge(
  (
    "primary":    $primary,
    "secondary":  $secondary,
    "success":    $success,
    "info":       $info,
    "warning":    $warning,
    "danger":     $danger,
    "light":      $light,
    "dark":       $dark
  ),
  $theme-colors
);

// Set a specific jump point for requesting color jumps
$theme-color-interval:      8% !default;

// The yiq lightness value that determines when the lightness of color changes from "dark" to "light". Acceptable values are between 0 and 255.
$yiq-contrasted-threshold:  150 !default;

// Customize the light and dark text colors for use in our YIQ color contrast function.
$yiq-text-dark:             $gray-900 !default;
$yiq-text-light:            $white !default;

// fusv-disable
$blue-100: tint-color($blue, 8) !default;
$blue-200: tint-color($blue, 6) !default;
$blue-300: tint-color($blue, 4) !default;
$blue-400: tint-color($blue, 2) !default;
$blue-500: $blue !default;
$blue-600: shade-color($blue, 2) !default;
$blue-700: shade-color($blue, 4) !default;
$blue-800: shade-color($blue, 6) !default;
$blue-900: shade-color($blue, 8) !default;

$indigo-100: tint-color($indigo, 8) !default;
$indigo-200: tint-color($indigo, 6) !default;
$indigo-300: tint-color($indigo, 4) !default;
$indigo-400: tint-color($indigo, 2) !default;
$indigo-500: $indigo !default;
$indigo-600: shade-color($indigo, 2) !default;
$indigo-700: shade-color($indigo, 4) !default;
$indigo-800: shade-color($indigo, 6) !default;
$indigo-900: shade-color($indigo, 8) !default;

$purple-100: tint-color($purple, 8) !default;
$purple-200: tint-color($purple, 6) !default;
$purple-300: tint-color($purple, 4) !default;
$purple-400: tint-color($purple, 2) !default;
$purple-500: $purple !default;
$purple-600: shade-color($purple, 2) !default;
$purple-700: shade-color($purple, 4) !default;
$purple-800: shade-color($purple, 6) !default;
$purple-900: shade-color($purple, 8) !default;

$pink-100: tint-color($pink, 8) !default;
$pink-200: tint-color($pink, 6) !default;
$pink-300: tint-color($pink, 4) !default;
$pink-400: tint-color($pink, 2) !default;
$pink-500: $pink !default;
$pink-600: shade-color($pink, 2) !default;
$pink-700: shade-color($pink, 4) !default;
$pink-800: shade-color($pink, 6) !default;
$pink-900: shade-color($pink, 8) !default;

$red-100: tint-color($red, 8) !default;
$red-200: tint-color($red, 6) !default;
$red-300: tint-color($red, 4) !default;
$red-400: tint-color($red, 2) !default;
$red-500: $red !default;
$red-600: shade-color($red, 2) !default;
$red-700: shade-color($red, 4) !default;
$red-800: shade-color($red, 6) !default;
$red-900: shade-color($red, 8) !default;

$orange-100: tint-color($orange, 8) !default;
$orange-200: tint-color($orange, 6) !default;
$orange-300: tint-color($orange, 4) !default;
$orange-400: tint-color($orange, 2) !default;
$orange-500: $orange !default;
$orange-600: shade-color($orange, 2) !default;
$orange-700: shade-color($orange, 4) !default;
$orange-800: shade-color($orange, 6) !default;
$orange-900: shade-color($orange, 8) !default;

$yellow-100: tint-color($yellow, 8) !default;
$yellow-200: tint-color($yellow, 6) !default;
$yellow-300: tint-color($yellow, 4) !default;
$yellow-400: tint-color($yellow, 2) !default;
$yellow-500: $yellow !default;
$yellow-600: shade-color($yellow, 2) !default;
$yellow-700: shade-color($yellow, 4) !default;
$yellow-800: shade-color($yellow, 6) !default;
$yellow-900: shade-color($yellow, 8) !default;

$green-100: tint-color($green, 8) !default;
$green-200: tint-color($green, 6) !default;
$green-300: tint-color($green, 4) !default;
$green-400: tint-color($green, 2) !default;
$green-500: $green !default;
$green-600: shade-color($green, 2) !default;
$green-700: shade-color($green, 4) !default;
$green-800: shade-color($green, 6) !default;
$green-900: shade-color($green, 8) !default;

$teal-100: tint-color($teal, 8) !default;
$teal-200: tint-color($teal, 6) !default;
$teal-300: tint-color($teal, 4) !default;
$teal-400: tint-color($teal, 2) !default;
$teal-500: $teal !default;
$teal-600: shade-color($teal, 2) !default;
$teal-700: shade-color($teal, 4) !default;
$teal-800: shade-color($teal, 6) !default;
$teal-900: shade-color($teal, 8) !default;

$cyan-100: tint-color($cyan, 8) !default;
$cyan-200: tint-color($cyan, 6) !default;
$cyan-300: tint-color($cyan, 4) !default;
$cyan-400: tint-color($cyan, 2) !default;
$cyan-500: $cyan !default;
$cyan-600: shade-color($cyan, 2) !default;
$cyan-700: shade-color($cyan, 4) !default;
$cyan-800: shade-color($cyan, 6) !default;
$cyan-900: shade-color($cyan, 8) !default;
// fusv-enable
```

Update 1 :

This is what I get when I try command line method on `-variables.scss` file from the repo

```
$ sass _variables.scss matrix.css
Error: (0: 0, 1: 0.25rem, 2: 0.5rem, 3: 1rem, 4: 1.5rem, 5: 3rem) isn't a valid CSS value.
    ╷
251 │ $negative-spacers: negativify-map($spacers) !default;
    │                                   ^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  _variables.scss 251:35  root stylesheet
```

Comment: So it means prepros is not giving any error and it's creating css file on the fly. Only the issue is css files is empty with 0 bytes size. Right ?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Comment: What I think is your file contains only the definition part. Means it only contains the variables with assigned values. To compile this file you need to use those variables somewhere then after compilation prepros will replace that variable by the actual hex value. Hope you got my point

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow. Currently I am trying command line `sass input.scss output.css`. I can switch back to Prepros if it helps checking something.

Comment: added answer below, hope it will help. Let me know if you still have query

Comment: Please see this : https://i.imgur.com/HANH8fQ.png

Comment: I tried Prepros on the full repo. It said some mixin missing.

Comment: So you can see that your prepros is showing error while compiling the file. There is missing mixin.

Comment: Some where in your scss file you are calling that mixin and your files dont contain that mixin definition so prepros is throwing error. You need to find out that mixin call

Comment: Can you please check the code I have given above ? There is no @include in that. Are you able to compile them as css ? If you can check, thanks.

Comment: I am able to see mixin call in https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss

Comment: Sorry Priyanka, I am still not able to figure out how to get out of this. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203310/discussion-between-priyanka-and-user227495).

Comment: Make sure you're including _functions.scss. That's where that mixin is defined. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_functions.scss

Comment: You can add following

@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions', '~bootstrap/scss/variables';

in my main scss file to overcome this issue.

Comment: @Priyanka System hung, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCSS File : style.scss

```
@import "../base/_vaiables.scss"
body {
    background: $white;
}
```

SCSS File : _variables.scss

```
$white : #ffffff;
```

Now your need to compile style.scss file by prepross or command line.
Then it will generate style.css as below

style.css

```
body {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: You were right from the beginning. I failed to understand. After a lot of trial and error, I finally used the above answer to get my hex codes out of the SCSS file. Thanks. :)

Comment: I had to fix _variables.scss and _functions.scss. Move a bit of code across these files to meet the dependencies. Most of them happened while trial and error.

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question, I think there is some information here that might be relevant but as a noob it is very hard to put all the pieces together.

I too have this exact same issue above, but only with bootstrap 4.3.1 not bs4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include only `_variables.scss` from Bootstrap.

You will get next error:

```
SassError: (0: 0, 1: 0.25rem, 2: 0.5rem, 3: 1rem, 4: 1.5rem, 5: 3rem) isn't a valid CSS value.
    ╷
254 │ $negative-spacers: if($enable-negative-margins, negativify-map($spacers), null) !default;
    │                                                                ^^^^^^^^
```

To fix this you need to import `_funcitons.scss` before `_variables.scss` import like this:

```
@import "../../bootstrap/functions";
@import "../../bootstrap/variables";

body {
    font-size: $font-size-base;
}
```